# delete line containing a specific string in shell

Tags: string, shell, sed, line

I want to delete a line containing a specific string from my file. I do it like that:

```
 sed -i "/example/d" myfile
```

But my file contains many lines containing strings that contain the  string that I want to delete.
for example my file contains lines as bellow and I want to delete only the first line that contains "example":

```
myfile:
 example
 example1
 example2
 ..
```

My question is how to do if want to delete only the line that contains exactly my string "example" and keep the other ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple. Be more specific.

```
sed -i "/\bexample\b/d" myfile
```

Comment: how to delete a specific line with a string and also the line immediately above it?